# Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList'. 'Join' not found. in linq

Tags: c#, linq, sharepoint

I am trying to join three lists using LINQ query.But am getting the error as "Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList'.  'Join' not found. in linq".Please help me to fix this.

ascx.cs

```
 using (SPSite oSPsite = SPContext.Current.Site)
        {
            using (SPWeb oSPWeb = oSPsite.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPList projectlist = oSPWeb.Lists[CustomListEnum.GemsList.ProjectList.ConvertToString()];
                SPList clientlist = oSPWeb.Lists[CustomListEnum.GemsList.ClientList.ConvertToString()];
                SPList timelist = oSPWeb.Lists[CustomListEnum.GemsList.WorkList.ConvertToString()];
                List<ClientListData> clientlistdetails = (from project in projectlist
                                                          join client in clientlist on project.ProjectName equals client
                                                          join time in timelist on client.Project equals time
                                                          select new ClientListData
                                                          {
                                                              ID = client.ID,
                                                              Name = client.Name,
                                                              ProjectTotal = projectlist.GetItems(GetQueryForProjectByClient(client.Name)).Count(),
                                                              ActiveProjects = projectlist.GetItems(GetQueryForActiveProjectbyClient(client.Name)).Count(),
                                                              Billable = timelist.GetItems(GetQueryForBillableProjectbyClient(client.Name, project.ProjectName)).Count(),
                                                              UnBillable = timelist.GetItems(GetQueryForUnbillableProjectbyClient(client.Name, project.ProjectName)).Count(),
                                                           DateCreated = client.DateCreated
                                                          }).ToList();}}
```

Comment: It is true. SPList does not contain Join(). Apart from that also, your entire code implementation is incorrect. Unlike SQL queries, SharePoint expects SPQuery which returns ListItemCollections and not your standard DataRows. Check this out. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your comment..